# In Python, allowing subsequent code to be executed after Tkinter dialog is shown

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using Tkinter in Python to display an dialog box. After the dialog box is shown, subsequent code should execute regardless whether user has closed the dialog box or not.

I tried to use thread to create the dialog box in a new thread, but it doesn't seem to work. I suppose I would need to encapsulate the subsequent code in a separate thread which I do not wish to.

```
def alert(title, message):
    box = Tk()
    box.title(title)
    Message(box, text=message, bg='red',
      fg='ivory').pack(padx=1, pady=1) #, relief=GROOVE
    Button(box, text="Close", command=box.destroy).pack(side=BOTTOM)
    box.geometry('300x150')
    thread.start_new_thread(box.mainloop())
    hello()

def hello():
    print 'hello!'
```

The issue with the code above is that 'hello!' will only be printed after user has dismissed the alert box. How can I modify my code to have hello() (or any subsequent code for that matter) to be executed regardless of the status of the dialog box?

Comment: Are you creating a traditional script where you want to pop up a dialog in-between other blocks of code, or are you trying to create a GUI that displays an alert? If the former, Tkinter isn't designed to work that way. You would be better off spawning a separate command to display the alert.

Comment: In-between my code, I like to display a dialog box to show a message for the user's information, but I do not want the rest of the code to halt till user close the dialog box.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
def alert(title, message):
    box = Tk()
    box.title(title)
    Message(box, text=message, bg='red',
      fg='ivory').pack(padx=1, pady=1) #, relief=GROOVE
    Button(box, text="Close", command=box.destroy).pack(side=BOTTOM)
    box.geometry('300x150')
    box.after(10, hello)
    box.mainloop()
```

Comment: `after` is certainly a good way to cause something to happen in the future, but I don't think that's what the OP is really after. They want to do something more like `alert(); hello(); more_code();`

Comment: @BryanOakley is right, the function alert(title, message) is just to allow me to call up a dialog box to inform the user of an event but while doing so, I do not want my code to stop executing while waiting for user to acknowledge the dialog box.

Comment: Well instead of '10' put '0' for the delay time. Pretty much the same effect, a new thread is launched.